# Position of picture changed

Tags: html, css

The position of the picture was the same until I changed the pictures.

[These are the position of the pictures with the old photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quJNJ.png)

[This is the position with the new photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9XAA.png)

```css
.column-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.column-3 {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding
}

.section-team {
  text-align: center;
}

.members {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.upm {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-team" id="team">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>team members</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <img src="img/Picture1.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <img src="img/Picture2.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <img src="img/Picture3.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <img src="img/Picture5.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <img src="img/Picture4.png" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <img src="img/Picture6.jpg" class="members" alt="members" style="width:50%">
    <h3>Adam</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="column-3">
    <img src="img/upm.jpg" class="upm" alt="upm" style="width:30%">
    <h4>Partnered with UPM</h4>
  </div>
```

I hope someone can show me how to the make position  of the current photos like the one in the first picture.

Comment: The original pictures were all the same size; it is likely the new ones are of different sizes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey know anyway i can change the size of the pictures? or do you know a way how to change it with css

Comment: Set the size of the pictures in CSS by giving them a `height` and `width`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey so i have to find a certain height and width until the pictures are in the position as the first link?

Comment: Or clear the float on every fourth div

Comment: @HereticMonkey do you know how to find the height and width of the photos in the first picture

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not treating your divs like containers.  ".column-2" and ".column-3" should not be defining by how much space the image takes up, but how much space the thing that holds the image takes up.

To fix this, you need to accommodate the padding with calc() based widths.  If a container has 35px of padding, you need to subtract that from the container's width to make sure that it all adds up to 100% after non-relative measurements are excluded.  Secondly, .column-3 needs to be based on 100% width if it is the only column in the row.

A third suggestion (though not absolutely necessary to make this script work) is to refactor your columns. These classes are not going to be very reusable as they are so to make sure you can use these same classes in other places, you want to do the following:  Most themes have a maximum number of columns supported (usually 12), so you name each column class name based on how many of these 12 columns the element will occupy.  Since you want .column-2 to be 1/3rd of a row, you would name it .column-4, and since you want .column-3 to be a whole row, you would name it .column-12.  You can make additional classes for all of the other divisions as needed.  You should also standardise the behaviors of your columns so they all use the same floats and paddings, and only use the sub-elements to give them their unique properties.

```
.column-4 { /* was column-2 */
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* includes padding as part of width */
  width: 33.3%; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.column-12 { /* was column-3 */
  float: left; /* made the same as column-4 for consistency */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* includes padding as part of width */
  width: 100%; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px; /* moved here from upm for consistancy. */
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.upm {
  float: right; /* Added float right here instead of column-12 to make column-12 more reusable. */
  padding-top: 20px; /* subtracted 5px since it inherits 5px from it's container. */
  /* removed padding: 5px; because it should belong to column-12 */
}

/* make sure to update column class names in your HTML to match */
```

Comment: it arranged them in order but didnt make the picture in the bottom row go to the second row

Comment: the thing is the empty slot on the second row  cant be filled no matter what picture i put

Comment: Try the above changes.  I've already tested it and it works; so, if it does not it's probably because you have additional CSS rules somewhere you are not including.

Comment: Why `calc()` when you can `border-box`?

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Both work, but yes, border-box is probably a better solution for ease of maintenance, thanks.

Comment: @Nosajimiki how do i make the text and the picture align to the bottom right of the section? right now i cant add padding on the right ofthe UPM picture and i cant find a away to put text on top of it

Comment: I would suggest asking that as a separate question since it would be hard to adequately answer in comments.